# When are props updated in the VueJS lifecycle

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to access a prop in the mounted hook of the vuejs lifecycle but it doesn't seem to have any value

My (really simplified) component looks like this:

```
export default {
    props: [
        'columns',
    ],
    mounted: function() {
        console.log(this.columns)
    }
}
```

The parent looks like this:

```
<script>
    import DatatableHeader from './DatatableHeader.vue';

    export default {
        data: {
            columns: [{'heading': 'Column 1'}, {'heading': 'Column 2'}]
        },
        components: {
            'datatableheader'   : DatatableHeader,
        }
    }
</script>
```

The component renders correctly but the output from the mounted function is an empty array, it seems like  timing issue to me.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a different lifecycle hook that I should use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is you can access the props in the mounted hook. If you check this fiddle you'll see the alert successfully shows the heading of a column. https://jsfiddle.net/yj3k1wLx/1/ The fact that your program is running but returning an empty array seems to indicate that you are not actually passing in the columns array. `<test :columns="columns">` Compare the fiddle to your code and see if maybe you have the wrong reference or variable.

**Update**
The simple answer to your comment is to change the root hook to created instead of mounted. But, I get the feeling your going about this the wrong way. Now I haven't seen your code, but I think the problem lies in your updating the array. Read the caveats here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats and then check out this updated demo https://jsfiddle.net/yj3k1wLx/4/

Comment: Thanks for the update! Yes your example works great. I have updated the fiddle to show what is happening to me. https://jsfiddle.net/bernieblakeney/yj3k1wLx/3/.  The problem I have is that I am loading the columns array in the mounted hook of the parent. I think I need some sort of computed property or watch to track when the parent array is changed. Not sure what order the mounted events fired in but it appears that the child component is mounted before the parent.

Comment: @niggle check my updated answer and see if it helps.